# concatenate files and print

Tags: printing, cat

I need to concatenate files and print it. However I also want to add a header (name of the file) when concatenating, to distinguish the files.

Example:

```
file1.txt
content of file1.txt

file2.txt
content of file2.txt

....
....
```

what are the ways of going about this? I am using the lp command to print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in file?.txt ; do echo $i ; cat $i ; done | lp
```

Comment: question: how come you used ; instead of > are they the same? Shouldn't it be echo abc > cat ....

Comment: > is used to direct output to a file. It can't be used to pipe to a command. "echo abc ; cat abc" executes two separated commands.